# Find the minimum value above a certain threshold

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the min value for values equal to or above 3. this doesn't work

```
A = [21,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1, 8, 9, 10]; 
idx=find(3<A & A==min(A)); 
A(idx)
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Also please create a shorter title and explain the issue in the body of your question. And be more specific as to what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [logical indexing in Matlab](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

```
min( A( A >= 3 ) )
```